# Is there a way to export an FMU that runs on Mac from a Windows or Linux based software?

Tags: fmi

I currently work on simulating a system using a Windows or Linux based software, that can export FMI 2.0 compliant models. Can I run that exported FMU from within a Simulink model running on a Mac?

I tried exporting the FMU from a Linux machine and when I attempted to run the model on Mac, I got an error “Cannot load the library”

Answer (score 1):

You need to export an FMI model containing a MAC compatible binary, as in compiled for MAC. The FMI standard has defined a folder structure so that an FMU can contain binaries for multiple architectures. Most prevalent are probably linux and windows in 32/64 bit but MAC is certainly an option.

Clarify if the tool you export the FMU from supports MAC or at least an FMI export for that architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately the software does not support Mac, it only works on windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

If your exporting tools supports export of C-Code FMUS (you find it in the sources folder of the FMU, when you unpack the zip file), you can recompile it for mac, e.g. using the command line call or GUI of fmpy. (add platform binary), see e.g.,
https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/main/tests/test_c_code.py

Comment: Unfortunately the fmu package only contains the binaries directory and the xml file.